# different prefix: "/" and "http:/localhost:3000" with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using devise with rails 5.1.4. When I'm trying to sign in with a wrong password I get this error:

> different prefix: "/" and "http:/localhost:3000"

I'm using rbenv with ruby 2.4.1. I had the same problem with ruby 2.3.3.

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
    /home/badr/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/pathname.rb:520:in `relative_path_from'
devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:58:in `recall'
devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:39:in `respond'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:242:in `block in action'
devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/failure_app.rb:21:in `call'
devise (4.3.0) lib/devise/delegator.rb:5:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:143:in `call_failure_app'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:129:in `process_unauthenticated'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:44:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Any idea where this might come from ?

**Update:**
I created a workspace on cloud9 to see if the project works fine on an other machine and indeed it does! So it's seems like something is wrong with my ruby installation. Before the issue started to happen I had destroyed the project folder on my linux machine and cloned it again from bitbucket.

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4096

Comment: I'm going to install ruby 2.2.6 see if the same problem happens...

Comment: Your error message says `http:/`, shouldn't that be `http://`?

Comment: Yes there's a '/' missing but why ?

Comment: `http:/` is used for intranet addresses I think, but maybe thats the error

Comment: can you show your routes.rb?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Devise Workflow of your action.

You filled the form [`session/new.html.erb`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb). Devise uses the [`form_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) to bind the form to an object and use the `RESTful` Routes from your `routes.rb` file.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

This `form_for` tag will generate the following html form, `resource` will be replaced with an object based on the `User` or `Admin` Model by your [`SessionsController#new` action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L8) with the code `self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)`

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" method="post" class="nifty_form">
```

The html form will trigger a `POST` request to url `/users` when you click on the `submit` button.

The `POST` request will be received from your *Server router* which based on the settings you configured on your `routes.rb` will decide how to *respond*.

If your `routes.rb` file is configured as with *Devise* guidelines, this will be your `routes.rb` file

```
devise_for :users
```

which generates the following routes

```
user_session POST   /users/sign_in                    {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"create"}
```

so when the `request` is received from the server it should be handled from the [`sessions_controller.rb#create` action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L16). You can display this controllers on Github or in your GEMS installed in your RVM or RBENV folders. You can also debug them by setting a `binding.pry`

```
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```

When you decide to use the wrong authentication, you are calling this [method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise%2FStrategies%2FDatabaseAuthenticatable:authenticate!)

```
def authenticate!
resource  = password.present? && mapping.to.find_for_database_authentication(authentication_hash)
hashed = false

if validate(resource){ hashed = true; resource.valid_password?(password) }
  remember_me(resource)
  resource.after_database_authentication
  success!(resource)
end

mapping.to.new.password = password if !hashed && Devise.paranoid
fail(:not_found_in_database) unless resource
end
```

So when you give invalid password and email, `validate(resource){ hashed = true; resource.valid_password?(password) }` will return false and execute this code

```
mapping.to.new.password = password if !hashed && Devise.paranoid
fail(:not_found_in_database) unless resource
```

which for some reasons will redirect to the wrong url.

I believe this code is meant to show an error in your page, the view `session/new.html.erb`. So I believe there is not `GET request` in Devise standard controller, but just re-rendering the view with the error message.

So my question is, did you overwrite the Devise controller to give it this behavior? Could you share with us your `routes.rb` file and the output of `rake routes`?